# DBIx::Class upgrade in Catalyst (DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader)

Tags: database, perl, migration, catalyst, dbix-class

I am using Catalyst for an application and am getting ready to upgrade the production version to the next major release. In the new release a lot of changes have been made to the database. The ORM in Catalyst is created with DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader from the physical development database. In frameworks like rails the ORM works the other way around and migrations from one version to the next are simple.

Can anyone tell me whether there are solutions for creating an alter script that changes an old version of the database to a newer? I tried mysqldiff, MySQL Workbench (synchronize option is broken), RedGate, Toad for MySQL and a number of other tools. There has to be an easier way to do this in a Catalyst application or DBIx::Class model for that matter.

Can anyone help me? Thx

Rob

Comment: Hi Rob. I'd be curious to know why the Red Gate's MySQL Compare tool didn't meet your expectations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout [DBIx::Class::DeploymentHandler](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aDeploymentHandler). It isn’t the easiest to dive into but it is probably exactly what you want. There is a nice, if brief, write-up of some of its power here–[DBIx::Class::DeploymentHandler is Awesome](http://www.pythian.com/news/19797/dbixclassdeploymenthandler-is-awesome/).

Comment: Hey Ashley, thanks for the reply. Have to take a bit closer look at the module, but it looks exactly like what I want with a bit more :)